# Trying to send different Outlook messages depending on if "0" is in the column C,D and E next to email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to automate emails for deliverable required by my team with a Macro.  In Excel I have a Name in Column A, Email in Column B, and Columns C and D indicate if I have received KPI information and Comments and Org Chart from the team.
[sample of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zi8oQ.png)

[image]

I am attempting to use and `If Then Else statement` to loop though Column C,D and E and send an email if the value in those cells is **`"0"`**

Getting a Else without IF error even though I made sure to space out the statements according to their specific rules.

Frankly, I'm not sure the If Then Else statement is what I need to have my macro loop though three columns and send emails to the contact in the row asking for the item with a **`"0"`** in the cell

```
Sub EMail()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMailKPI As Object
    Dim OutmailComment As Object
    Dim OutmailOrg As Object
    Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    On Error GoTo cleanup
    For Each cell In Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "C").Value) = "0" Then

            Set OutMailKPI = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Reminder"
                .Body = "Dear, " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                      & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "KPI"
                '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
                .Send  'Or use Display

    Else

        Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells (xlCellTypeConstants)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           LCase(Cells(cell.Row, "D").Value) = "0" Then

            Set OutmailComment = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .To = cell.Value
                .Subject = "Reminder"
                .Body = "Dear, " & Cells(cell.Row, "A").Value _
                      & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                        "Comment"
                '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
                .Send  'Or use Display

            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

cleanup:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If I have both the KPI and Comments but not the Org chart when I run the Macro only and email with the body "Please send Org chart" will be sent to that contact.

I will indicate if I have received the item with a 0 in the cell under each `column labeled:KPI`,`Comments,OrgChart`.

Comment: Please use Option Explicit first to find such errors like this: OutMailKPI and OutMailComment are set, but OutMail is used. The coderow Columns(„B“)… is useless.

Comment: Please remove `On Error Resume Next` or `On Error GoTo` from your code while you are in debugging mode, also where is `end with` on your 1st `With OutMail`?

Comment: When you say `0` is that zero or blank or you mean the letter `o`, I see you are using `LCase` try using `trim` if its bank then use `vbnullstring`

Comment: yes, zero is the value required not to send the email.

Comment: see sample of data link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Try the following*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub EMail()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Sht.Range("A2", Sht.Range("A100").End(xlUp))
        DoEvents

       If Sht.Cells(Cell.Row, "B").Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
           Sht.Cells(Cell.Row, "C").Value = "0" Or _
           Sht.Cells(Cell.Row, "D").Value = "0" Or _
           Sht.Cells(Cell.Row, "E").Value = "0" Then               

            Dim MissingItem As String
            Select Case "0"
                Case Sht.Cells(Cell.Row, "C").Value
                    MissingItem = "KPI's"
                Case Sht.Cells(Cell.Row, "D").Value
                    MissingItem = "Comments"
                Case Sht.Cells(Cell.Row, "E").Value
                    MissingItem = "Org Chart"
            End Select

            Dim OutMailKPI As Object
            Set OutMailKPI = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            With OutMailKPI
                .To = Sht.Cells(Cell.Row, "B").Value
                .Subject = "Reminder"
                .Body = "Dear, " & Sht.Cells(Cell.Row, "A").Value _
                      & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & MissingItem
                .Display
            End With

        End If
    Next Cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```